Unknown flow metadata
I am modifying an existing contact flow written by developers who are now unavailable.
In one block it is using the metadata attribute:
$.CallbackNumber

When I check the available attributes in AWS Documentation this field is not listed. Is this some hidden attribute or something that has been deprecated and should be migrated to a new value? In our use case it appears so far to be the same as
$.CustomerEndpoint.Address

but I do not know if I can rely on that always being the case.
Thanks.

I think you are right in that it has been deprecated. It probably refers to the System - Customer callback number attribute, which doesn't have a json path reference. This attribute stores the number that a customer will be called back on when using the callback functionality in Connect.
It will often be the same as $.CustomerEndpoint.Address as most of the time when doing a callback you will be calling the customer back on the number they originally called from. But it could be different if your flows allow callers to set the callback number to something other than the number they called from. e.g. when they have a blocked CLI.
You can use a Set Attributes block to get this "hidden" attribute and assign it to a user defined attribute if you need to use the attribute elsewhere in your contact flow.
